# jQuery live event on iPad...why doesn't it work?

Tags: jquery, ipad

I'm using jQuery to develop webapps on the iPad and it seems the jQuery live event doesn't work... This was the case when I was working with the SDK iPad emulator and now that I have the iPad to work on, its still the same (I was hoping it was an emulator fault). Running the same code on a web kit build works fine.

I'm just wondering if anyone else is having this problem? If there is a fix? or if it's me? Hoping someone can help as my code is becoming really bloated having to rebind clicks etc after ajax calls.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 18):

The issue is for some reason mobile safari does not attach the click events to some DOM elements, So you have to manually attach them.

```
$('.header').live('click',get_location_input);
```

and when you add this later it works on the ipad

```
<div class='header' onclick=''>Station Info</div>
```

**here is where I got my information**

http://skillfulness.blogspot.com/2010/11/workaround-for-jquery-live-event.html

Answer (score 3):

I had to use the jQuery .delegate event which seems to do the trick binding click to an element after an ajax call.

Answer (score -1):

'cursor: pointer' for the perticular ID in css file works for me..