# iPad jquery live('click') Issue

Tags: jquery, ipad, mobile-safari, modal-dialog

I have a modal dialog which closes when someone clicks on the overlay using the following function and it works on all browsers except for in iPad and iPhone Safari.

```
$(".ui-widget-overlay").live('click', function() { 
//mycode to close modal dialog
});
```

I tried $(".ui-widget-overlay").click but that doesn't work.

There is an issue with live function not working on iPad if there is no onclick attribute on the element [jQuery live event on iPad...why doesn't it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344960/jquery-live-event-on-ipad-why-doesnt-it-work)

So I tried to add the attribute before the live function and still it doesn't work. Here is what I am doing:

```
$(".ui-widget-overlay").attr('onclick', '');
$(".ui-widget-overlay").live('click', function() { 
//mycode to close modal dialog
});
```

Has anyone found a solution to this?

Comment: Are you sure `click` even is even triggered? There is tap-events family on iPads.

Comment: I tried this but still it didnt work:
$(".ui-widget-overlay").bind('tap', onclick);

Comment: I didn't say there is an event with name `tap`, but there is `touchstart`. Also you probably need to look at jquery mobile

Comment: touchstart event also doesn't work

Comment: it does work. Please stop wasting your time and read jquery mobile documentation

Comment: works with touchstart

Answer (score 0):

```
$j(".telephonePopup").dialog({
    open: function (event) {
        $j('.ui-widget-overlay').live("touchstart click", function() {
            $j(".telephonePopup").dialog("close");
            return false;
        });

                    // if you want also to stop scrolling while popup is displayed
        document.ontouchmove = function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
        }
    },
    close: function (event) {
        $j('html').removeClass('stop-scrolling');
        document.ontouchmove = null;
    },
```